# Background image not displaying in java project

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel, embedded-resource

The variable was made, the image is loaded into the variable and the paintComponent is asked to display the image in my JPanel. I can't see my mistake.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Main();
        frame.setSize(1524, 715);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Animatieproject Stijn Mannaerts: Free Kick");
        frame.setContentPane(new Voetbalveld());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class Voetbalveld extends JPanel {

    private ImageIcon afbIntro;

    public Voetbalveld() {

        afbIntro = new ImageIcon("scr/afbeeldingen/Intro.jpg");

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        afbIntro.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Look through today's questions on embedded resources, it has been covered several times!

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), especially the last link. Hope it might be able to help you somewhat :-)

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how painting is done. Why not use Graphics.drawImage() instead? Check out this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me. Make sure you don't want `src` instead of `scr`. Next, if your image folder is inside source folder of your project then you might want to try this:

```
afbIntro = new ImageIcon(Voetbalveld.class.getResourceAsStream("scr/afbeeldingen/Intro.jpg"));
```

or

```
afbIntro = new ImageIcon(Voetbalveld.class.getResourceAsStream("afbeeldingen/Intro.jpg"));
```

depending on your file structure. The path in the second example needs to be relative to the file `Main.java`.

Answer (score 0):

**The frame class**

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Jframe frame = new JFrame("Animatieproject Stijn Mannaerts: Free Kick");
        frame.setSize(1524, 715);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Voetbalveld());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

**The panel class**

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Voetbalveld extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {    
        ImageIcon afbIntro = new ImageIcon("scr/afbeeldingen/Intro.jpg");
        /*The following are two methods for image sizing,
         *Use the one that best fits your code:
         *
         *g.drawImage(afbIntro.getImage(), x, y, null); 
         *Fill in the arguments for x and y to locate your upper left corner
         *The image will be in it's original size with the designated upper left corner
         *
         *g.drawImage(afbIntro.getImage(), x, y, w, h, null);
         *Fill in the arguments for w and h to set the width and height of your image
         *The image will be in it's scaled size (w and h) and starting at the 
         *designated upper left corner (x and y)
         */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You spelled `src` wrong. You have `scr`.

```
"scr/afbeeldingen/Intro.jpg"
```

Fix that